# Generating pdf from html using Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn

I want to generate pdf from html. A `gem prawn` seems to be the most popular one for that. I downloaded the manual for it, but there is no information about how to generate pdf from html.

In particular, I need it to work on Heroku also, but that's the second goal.

So how can I generate pdf from **html** using `Prawn`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for [Pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit), it's second most popular gem [RubyToolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pdf_generation). It generate PDF from HTML using wkhtmltopdf. On [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit) is one older tutorial.

Comment: do you know if I can use it on Heroku without any troubles?

Comment: unfortunately I don't know, but it looks its should work fine. They are wkhtml fork for heroku users maintained by Pdfkit maintainers on [github](https://github.com/pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf-heroku)

Comment: does it support Unicode? I need to use Cyrillic alphabet for it.

Comment: however, I have the error `The switch --print-media-type, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored` (webrick) or it simply hangs and a connection resets after a period of time (unicorn).

Answer (score -8):

This is a sample code to generate pdf from html using prawn

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert the HTML code from the specified URL to a PDF document
    and send the document to the browser
/// </summary>
private void ConvertURLToPDF()
{
    string urlToConvert = textBoxWebPageURL.Text.Trim();

    // Create the PDF converter. Optionally the HTML viewer width can
        be specified as parameter
    // The default HTML viewer width is 1024 pixels.
    PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();

    // set the license key - required
    pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "R8nYyNnI2MjRxtjI29nG2drG0dHR0Q==";

    // set the converter options - optional
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfCompressionLevel = PdfCompressionLevel.Normal;
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;


    // set if header and footer are shown in the PDF - optional - default
        is false 
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowHeader = cbAddHeader.Checked;
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowFooter = cbAddFooter.Checked;
    // set if the HTML content is resized if necessary to fit the PDF
        page width - default is true
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.FitWidth = cbFitWidth.Checked;

    // set the embedded fonts option - optional - default is false
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.EmbedFonts = cbEmbedFonts.Checked;
    // set the live HTTP links option - optional - default is true
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.LiveUrlsEnabled = cbLiveLinks.Checked;

    // set if the JavaScript is enabled during conversion to a PDF - default
        is true
    pdfConverter.JavaScriptEnabled = cbClientScripts.Checked;

    // set if the images in PDF are compressed with JPEG to reduce the
        PDF document size - default is true
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.JpegCompressionEnabled = cbJpegCompression.Checked;

    // enable auto-generated bookmarks for a specified list of HTML selectors
        (e.g. H1 and H2)
    if (cbBookmarks.Checked)
    {
        pdfConverter.PdfBookmarkOptions.HtmlElementSelectors = new string[] { "H1", "H2" };
    }

    // add HTML header
    if (cbAddHeader.Checked)
        AddHeader(pdfConverter);
    // add HTML footer
    if (cbAddFooter.Checked)
        AddFooter(pdfConverter);

    // Performs the conversion and get the pdf document bytes that can

    // be saved to a file or sent as a browser response
    byte[] pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(urlToConvert);

    // send the PDF document as a response to the browser for download
    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    if (radioAttachment.Checked)
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                String.Format("attachment; filename=GettingStarted.pdf; size={0}", 
                pdfBytes.Length.ToString()));
    else
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                String.Format("inline; filename=GettingStarted.pdf; size={0}", 
                pdfBytes.Length.ToString()));
    response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
    // Note: it is important to end the response, otherwise the ASP.NET
    // web page will render its content to PDF document stream
    response.End();
}
```

Comment: why are you giving me an example in C#?